# Excell на web с расчетами

Tags: php, веб-программирование, excel

Подскажите, на сколько моя задача выполнима и есть ли инструменты под нее.
Вкратце, есть таблица excel с расчетами, формулами, перелинковками между вкладками. В целом очень много расчетов.

Можно ли запилить это на web интерфейс? Т.е. нужно сделать web форму, куда пользователь будет вводить данные, они будут подставляться в соответствующие поля в excel документе.

В этом документе будут производится расчеты, затем полученные данные нужно вывести в форме результатов уже на сайте.

Спасибо.

Comment: Можно. Я лично видел доклад на похожую тему. Но описывать все это в ответе не имеет смысла.

Comment: Безусловно можно. Как минимум через [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel). Есть подробная документация, в которой описано как и что подставлять. Эта библиотека даже позволяет стили ячеек менять и прочий, довольно обширный функционал.

Comment: Всё возможно. Но если вам известны формулы и алгоритм расчета, а пользователь вводит определенные исходные данные в форму (не редактирует собственно электронную таблицу), то зачем Excel? Нужно написать скрипт с требуемыми расчетами.

Comment: Дело в том, что одним скриптом не получится сделать. Формул порядка 500 и статичных данных порядка 7 000. Это слишком трудоемко переносить. да и корректировки потом в такой объем слишком сложно вносить. На PHPExcel и подобных можно прям с файлом синхронизироваться или это все нужно переносить (в плане формул и т.д.)?